# How to make an event: click on random area in ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

If I want to catch events on clicking RMB on Col1 and Col2, and events should be different, is there any chance to do that ?

[image]

Comment: Use the MouseDown event and call ListView.HitTest() to see what was clicked.  And fire your own event accordingly.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844306/can-i-detect-if-a-user-right-clicked-on-a-listview-column-header-in-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as  @HansPassant said add the mouseup event

```
void listview1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = listview1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
        ListViewHitTestInfo info = listview1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if ((item != null) && (info.SubItem != null))
        {
            //item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem) gives the column index
            MessageBox.Show(item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, Is it possible to do the same with `TreeView`, separate mouse click events on text area and other field of node if I use `myTreeView.FullSelectRow = true` ?

Comment: what do you want to retrieve here, in the listview you wanted the column index ,here ???? *the level may be* @Steven

Comment: just want to know where the click has been, for example: if in the text area then `true`, otherwise `false`, just want to know location

Comment: yes for sure replace `ListViewItem` by `TreeNode` and `ListViewHitTestInfo` by `TreeViewHitTestInfo` if `item` is null you're clicking out , else if (`info.Node` is null and item isn't) so you clicked at the expand button (+) else you selected your item

Answer (score 0):

Use DataGridView insted of ListView. DataGridView already supports cell click:

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "You have clicked " + (e.ColumnIndex + 1).ToString() + " cell inside " + (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString() + " row!";
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Click info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

ListView is not ment to be used with tabular data. It's primary use is for lists, good example is Windows Explorer.