# How to make Transparent Paint application to draw on screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I want to create a app that lets you draw on screen like [Epic Pen](https://epicpen.com/). I searched on google on how to do it but all I found was only how to draw static shapes (rectangles etc.) on the screen, not brushstrokes like in MSPaint. I thinked of making the form transparent by using TransparencyKey but it just lets clicks through it.. Is there any way for me to do this, without taking a screenshot and drawing on it? I want users to be able to switch between pen mode (draw on screen) and cursor mode (normal clicking).

Comment: Create a Layered Window and update it with 32-bit ARGB Bitmap whose alpha channel is all set to 1. Subsequently, draw your content on this bitmap.

Comment: Do you want to draw onto the screen or onto your form?

Comment: @TaW I want to draw on the screen, I just said I can use a transparent form to achieve it. You can download and install epic pen to understand what I mean.

Comment: The keyword for your question is Layered Window.

Comment: The clicktrough depends on which color you use for the tpkey. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217890/problems-with-opacity/35218643#35218643)

Comment: @jtxkopt can you give me a code example? I Don't know much about layered windows